# How to swipe ViewPager while the content is being scrolled?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am able to implement `TabLayout` with `ViewPager` nicely but when the content inside the `ViewPager` is being scrolled (the deceleration animation), I cannot swipe left and right to change to other fragments inside `ViewPager`. I have to wait until the scrolling animation stops and then swipe.

Below is some of my code snippets.

I have a simple `activity_main.xml` layout like below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/btmNavView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I then inflate a fragment containing `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` into the `LinearLayout` in the middle of the `activity_main.xml`. This layout can be seen below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.pchatanan.sontana.custom_views.AppTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/contactTabLayout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/contactViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The logic inside my fragment is below:

```
fragmentArray = new Fragment[]{new SimpleFragment(), new SimpleFragment(), new SimpleFragment()};
titleArray = new String[]{"fragment1", "fragment2", "fragment3"};

contactPagerAdapter = new AppPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragmentArray, titleArray);
contactViewPager.setAdapter(contactPagerAdapter);
contactViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragmentArray.length - 1);
contactTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(contactViewPager);
```

Comment: What is content of fragment, is it scrollview or recycler view.

Comment: @Khemraj it is a simple scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead defualt ViewPager.
Detect when `ScrollView` or `RecyclerView` is scrolling. Then call

```
viewPager.setPagingEnabled(pagingEnable);
```

If pagingEnable

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean isPagingEnabled = true;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You can do reverse to like you can disable `ScrollView` scroll when `ViewPager` is swiping

```
mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

Comment: This custom class allows disabling swiping but, in my case, I do not see any need to disable the swipe. How would this class fix my question since the default ViewPager is already enabling swiping by default?

Comment: Issue is that two touch are intercepted one is View pager and second is ScrollView, so you can disable one when other is touched. See updated answer too.

Comment: How do I handle the communication between ScrollView and ViewPager since they are in different fragments?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now I got it working and will post the answer here. It's a bit different from yours.

Comment: If i had time then would post complete answer.

Comment: I gave you idea.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what suggested by @Khemraj, the problem is the touch is not intercepted by ViewPager. It is only intercepted by the ScrollView. To fix this, we should allow ViewPage to intercept the touch when scrolling:

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
        viewPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }
});
```

A better implementation is to make use of CallBackListener onto the fragment containing the scrollView.